# nginx and SSL redirect

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, https

I have a nginx server which I use as a proxy.
I want to have all requests forwarded as normal http requests, expect request to api.mydomain.org, those request I want to run with ssl/https.

This works fine with the following:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name api.mydomain.org;
       return 301 https://api.mydomain.org$request_uri;
}

server {

        listen   443;
        server_name api.mydomain.org;

          location / {
                proxy_pass  http://backend;

                 proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                 proxy_redirect off;
                 proxy_buffering off;
                 proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                 proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
         }

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/api.mydomain.org/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/api.mydomain.org/server.key;
}
```

However, this will redirect all request to subdomains which are not specifically specified/qualified. E.g. a.mydomain.org or b.mydomain.org are sent to https://api.mydomain.org.

How do I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a default server block that will catch unknown Host headers and deny connecting to them.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}
```

You may want to add your public IP address(es) to your `server_name` directive in your first block to accept connections using HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 with the IP address.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have default_server set for the general server. Added that and it works perfect!